# Does square provide hosting service?

Tags: e-commerce, web-hosting, web-development-server, square, mern

I'm a student developer learning to build an eCommerce website. I currently have the front and back end implemented and hosted on Heroku (MERN). 
I've been reading the documentation on [Square](https://developer.squareup.com/us/en) they have an eCommerce website builder so I assume they can host my website. However, I couldn't find any information on how to do it.

Need Help!
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Square has [Weebly](https://www.weebly.com/) which technically will host your website, but it's a platform meant as a website-builder (not necessarily moving your backend+frontend code over). In order to host your current backend code, you'll need to find a different more traditional web-host provider.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a best compatible hosting platform with sqaure?

Comment: Any reasonable hosting platform should work, but it kind of depends on what your backend is going to be. Since Square just allows you to make API calls you can do it in nearly any language that supports HTTP requests. So, I can't really make any recommendations, sorry.